# Difference between for loop and return in a function

Tags: r, for-loop, return

I have written two functions named f and f2 as follow:

```
f<- function(n) {
  factorial <- 1
  if (as.integer(n)!=n | n<0)
    print("The factorial for this number does not exist")
  else if( n == 0 )
    print("Factorial of 0 is 1")
  else{
    return(n * factorial(n - 1))
    print(paste("The factorial of ",n,"is",factorial))}
}
```

and

```
f2<-function(n){
  factorial<-1
  if (as.integer(n)!=n | n<0){
    print("The factorial of this number does not exist")
  }else if (n==0){
    print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
  }else {
    for (i in 1:n)
      factorial<-factorial*i
    print(paste("The factorial of ",n,"is",factorial))
  }
}
```

My functions (f and f2) do the same thing (factorial). For the first function, I used "return" and for the second function I used "for loop". But when I compute, for example, f(5) and f2(5), the type of their output is different. The second code (function f2) gives me

```
"The factorial of  5 is 120"
```

as output and this is what I want, but the first code (function f) gives me

```
120
```

as output, I don't know why the first code does not execute the print command. I would like to see "The factorial of  5 is 120" for the first code, I mean f(5), too.

Comment: It looks like you have an explicit `return` before the `print` in `f()` function. Once this is executed, the function exits immediately (before printing). Try moving the `return` to after the `print` statement if you still want to return the value in addition to printing. You will also need to clarify your calculation of `factorial` in your `print` statement as well.

Comment: When I put "return" after "print" like below code:


> f<- function(n) {
+   factorial <- 1
+   if (as.integer(n)!=n | n<0)
+     print("The factorial for this number does not exist")
+   else if( n == 0 )
+     print("Factorial of 0 is 1")
+   else{
+     print(paste("The factorial of ",n,"is",factorial))
+     return(n * factorial(n - 1))}
+ }


> f(5)
[1] "The factorial of  5 is 1"
[1] 120

The output is not what I want.

Comment: What output do you want? If you just want to print "The factorial of 5 is 120" you can just remove the `return` completely, and keep: `print(paste("The factorial of ",n,"is",n * factorial(n - 1)))` This will have an implicit return of the text string.

Comment: My apologies - I reread your question and see your desired output. Please let me know if the above comment meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much Ben. Yes, your comment meets my needs.